# How do I set javascript variables or call functions with the razor syntax?

Tags: javascript, razor, visual-web-developer

This is a beginners question about web programming. Basically I have a page that shows a default address using the Google Map API. It works fine looking up "221B Baker Street, London, United Kingdom", but there is a textbox that I would like to be able to write an address in and then look it up. It's an cshtml-page and I know of the razor syntax

```
@{if(IsPost) { do something }}
```

So basically I would like to take the `Request.Form["FindAddress"];` from the textbox and and set it to the javascript myAddress variable so that the users address will be shown instead. But I don't know how to do it inline coding. It keeps giving me syntax errors when placing the IsPost-condition inside the -tag for the javascript functions. Here is the complete page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head id="head">
<title></title>
<link href="@Server.MapPath("~/Styles/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myAddress = "221B Baker Street, London, United Kingdom"; // how do I overwrite this if it is (isPost)?


    var map;
    var geocoder;
    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.5, -0.1), 10);
            map.setUIToDefault();

            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();                   
            showAddress(myAddress);
        }
    }
    function showAddress(address) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(address, function (point) { if (!point) { alert(address + " not found"); } else { map.setCenter(point, 15); var marker = new GMarker(point); map.addOverlay(marker); marker.openInfoWindow(address); } });
    }
</script>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="FindAddress" name="FindAddress" />
        </div>
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the below code, but I hope it will work. Basically I've put the conditional checking logic outside the script block and store the result in a variable and that is referenced in the javascript.

```
@{
  var address = "221B Baker Street, London, United Kingdom";

  if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
  {
    address = Request.Form["FindAddress"];
  }  
}

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var myAddress = "@address"; // how do I overwrite this if it is (isPost)?


    var map;
    var geocoder;
    function initialize() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.5, -0.1), 10);
        map.setUIToDefault();

        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        showAddress(myAddress);
      }
    }
    function showAddress(address) {
      geocoder.getLatLng(address, function (point) { if (!point) { alert(address + " not found"); } else { map.setCenter(point, 15); var marker = new GMarker(point); map.addOverlay(marker); marker.openInfoWindow(address); } });
    }
  </script>
```